# Progress 4gl to Excel Export with merged cell

Tags: excel, merge, cell, progress-4gl, openedge

How do you export from progress to excel with merged cell in the middle? when i try to export, it unmerged itself.
example expected output:

`merged cell with value 1 (3 cells)` `other value 1` `other value 1`

`merged cell with value 2 (3 cells)` `other value 2` `other value 2`

`merged cell with value 3 (3 cells)` `other value 3` `other value 3`

what my output is:

`unmerged cell value 1` `other value 1` `other value 1`

`unmerged cell value 2` `other value 2` `other value 2`

`unmerged cell value 3` `other value 3` `other value 3`

my export to excel code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE h-excel AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE h-sheet AS COM-HANDLE.
DEFINE VAR w-invname AS CHAR INITIAL "insert excel fill here".
CREATE "Excel.Application" h-excel.

h-sheet = h-excel:Workbooks:OPEN (w-invname,,FALSE,,,,,,,,,,FALSE) NO-ERROR.
h-excel:visible = true.

h-excel:Cells:Select.
/*h-excel:Selection:ClearContents.*/

h-excel:Run("loading").  /* Run the Macro, up to 31 optional   */
                           /* parameters can be passed           */
/*h-excel:Quit().*/            /* Tell Excel to quit                 */

/*h-excel:Range("A" + STRING(5)):VALUE = "Date Covered " + STRING(fifr) + " - " + STRING(fito).*/
h-excel:Range("A" + STRING(6)):VALUE = "As of " + cbMon + STRING(fiyear).

h-excel:Range("A12"):Select.
/*h-excel:Workbooks:SaveAs("c:\hckiv9\crd\forms\KMCDAT1.xls",43,,,,,).*/

RELEASE OBJECT h-sheet.
RELEASE OBJECT h-excel.

END PROCEDURE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I understand what you intend correctly, but there's no code to merge in the sample you provided. Here's something I put together quickly:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chExcel       AS COM-HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE chSpreadsheet AS COM-HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

/* Excel Creation, not relevant to the question, but preparing the answer */
create "Excel.Application" chExcel.
chExcel:WorkBooks:add. 
chExcel:sheets:item(1).
chSpreadsheet = chExcel:Worksheets("Sheet1").

   /* This line merges the two cells */
   chSpreadsheet:range('b2:c2'):merge().

   /* This line selects the merged cells */
   chSpreadsheet:range('b2:b2'):select().

   /* The next puts a value to B2 (Which is now merged with C2) */
   chSpreadsheet:cells(2,2) = 'test'.

   /* Make Excel visible to the user */
   chExcel:visible = true.

   /* Release handles, you may dispose of Excel here and add a quit if you 
      don't want to leave the screen hanging for the user */
   chSpreadsheet = ?.
   chExcel = ?.
```

So the line that actually replies your question is the merge I did right after the Excel startup. Now, range, unlike the cells (in which you may provide two comma-separated ints), as far as I know, will need a range string (in our case, B2:c2. But you can change that to suit your needs). Let me know if I've overlooked anything else you need. Hope this helps!